# "Actions taken on [Noun]" vs "Actions taken against [Noun]"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, cultural-correctness

I am an Australian working in the US.

During the workday I often find myself either reading documents or being corrected in how I write them myself when it concerns this grammatical usage.

Which is correct and why (example):

"We take actions on fraudulent customers"

*OR*

"We take actions against fraudulent customers"

As an Australian, I would have always previously written using the latter.

I am wondering if this is a US English vs British English difference.

ie "simplified english.... :-p

Answer (score 1):

I'd say both are correct, although "take action against" is more specific since it implies an action that would be negatively interpreted by the recipient.  "Take actions on" sounds more neutral to my ear.

Perhaps it depends on context.  "Take actions on" might be used to imply "investigate," or even just "contact." Take actions "against" sounds more decisive and punative.

Comment: It also seems like you would "take actions on" a matter. You would "take actions against" a person (or something being treated as a person, such as an organization).  It would sound odd to "take action on" a person  or "take actions against" a thing.